# Kenmore Ice Maker

Tags: electrical

I just changed the water inlet valve on my Kenmore ice maker.  Now it's time to reconnect the electrical wire harness, I'm not sure how it goes back on.  One side has two wires, the other only one.  Does it make a difference which way it is plugged in?

Comment: Are you sure the connector is not keyed so that it can only be connected in one way?

Comment: Download a service/owner manual. The information should be there. Also, didn't the parts came with an instruction?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.